# Multiplicar elementos de una lista en python

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo un duda y no he podido encontrar una solución en python. Como puedo multiplicar el primer elemento de una lista por los elementos subsecuentes. luego el siguiente elemento por los restantes?

Num = [1,9,7,5,9]

1 x 9,
1 x 7,
1 x 5,
1 x 9

Luego:
9 x 7,
9 x 5,
9 x 9

Y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al final de la lista.
Lo que quiero saber es si el resultado de alguna multiplicación es igual a un valor N, dado por el usuario.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el código que has intentado utilizar para lograr tu objetivo.

Comment: No he encontrado como hacerlo solo tengo el ciclo for que recorre la lista y es todo. Gracias por tu comentario 

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

La solución basada en probar hasta encontrar el producto debe iterar por los índices desde 0 hasta `len(numeros)` para dividir la lista en dos: el primer elemento que está en `numeros[i]` y los que están a su derecha, que son dados por el slice `numeros[i+1:]`. Seguidamente multiplicas el primero por cada uno de los del resto.

Pero dado que esto lo usas para buscar si el producto es uno dado, no tiene mucho sentido generar todos los productos posibles, pues tan pronto como aparezca el que buscabas puedes dar por terminada la búsqueda.

Por no repetir otras respuestas, voy a mostrar aquí cómo se puede implementar haciendo uso de un *generador*.

Un generador es una función que usa `yield` en vez de `return`, como la siguiente (que implementa el algoritmo que describí en el primer párrafo):

```
def productos(numeros):
    for i in range(len(numeros)):
        primero, resto = numeros[i], numeros[i+1:]
        for n in resto:
            yield primero*n
```

Fíjate cómo están ahí los bucles anidados necesarios para ir haciendo cada uno de los productos que necesitas, computado en la expresión `primero*n`. Pero en vez de poner `return` de esa expresión (que daría por terminada la función), ponemos `yield` que hace que el generador retorne ese valor pero quede "pausado" pudiéndose "reanudar" después para que prosiga iterando en el bucle hasta el siguiente `yield`.

Estos generadores pueden usarse dentro de un for, por ejemplo, si queremos computar todos los productos e imprimirlos por pantalla haríamos:

```
numeros = [1,9,7,5,9]

for p in productos(numeros):
    print(p)
```

lo que en este caso resultaría en:

```
9
7
5
9
63
45
81
35
63
45
```

También funcionan en otros lugares donde Python espere un iterable, por ejemplo en el constructor de una lista. Así que si en vez de imprimir los resultados los quieres en una lista basta hacer:

```
lista = list(productos(numeros))
```

El constructor `list()` iterará sobre el generador y construirá una lista con cada uno de los elementos que este vaya retornando (vía `yield`). Así que el resultado sería:

```
[9, 7, 5, 9, 63, 45, 81, 35, 63, 45]
```

**Además**, y esta es la razón que antes expliqué para preferir un generador, no necesitas realmente iterar por todos los posibles valores, pues puedes abortar el bucle cuando quieras. Por ejemplo, si queremos buscar si el número 81 está entre los resultados podemos hacer:

```
for p in productos(numeros):
  if p == 81:
     print("Encontrado el 81!")
     break
```

y esto ejecutará el generador hasta que se obtenga un 81, en cuyo caso el `break` finaliza el bucle evitando así tener que computar el resto de productos.

Lo mismo puedes lograr con la siguiente línea:

```
if any(p==81 for p in productos(numeros)):
    print("Encontrado el 81!")
```

En este caso `any()` espera un iterable compuesto de booleanos, y se detiene tan pronto como encuentre un `True`, retornando a su vez `True`, o bien retorna `False` si agota el iterable y no ha aparecido ningún `True`. En este caso el iterable es la expresión `p==81 for p in productos(numeros)`. Esta expresión es otro tipo de generador que es también *lazy*, es decir, que no realiza todas las iteraciones sino que las va generando de una en una. Así, extrae el primer valor de `p` del generador `productos()` y lo compara con 81. Como es `False`, genera el valor `False` para `any()`, y por tanto éste pide otro elemento. Entonces se extrae el segundo elemento de `producto()` y se compara con 81, etc.. hasta que uno sea igual a 81 en cuyo caso `any()` encuentra un `True` y termina retornando `True` haciendo que el `if` se cumpla.

Answer (score 4):

Buen día,

Podrías crear dos ciclos `for` uno para recorrer cada elemento de la lista, que será el primer factor, es decir `multiplicando`, el segundo `for` será para obtener el segundo factor, es decir el `multiplicador`, para eso puedes segmentar (Usar `slices`) la lista y con esos dos números obtener el `producto` ([Partes de la multiplicación](https://www.significados.com/multiplicacion/)).

Ejemplo:

```
Num = [1, 9, 7, 5, 9]

resultados = []
# Recorremos todos los elementos de la lista, será el multiplicando
for n in range(len(Num)):
    # Recorremos los elementos siguientes después de n (Usando slices), será el multiplicador
    for m in Num[n+1:]:
        # Creamos una tupla donde mostramos el valor del índice n, el valor de m y la multiplicación de n*m
        # Es decir (multiplicando, multiplicador, producto)
        resultados.append((Num[n], m, Num[n] * m))
print(resultados)
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
[(1, 9, 9), (1, 7, 7), (1, 5, 5), (1, 9, 9), (9, 7, 63), (9, 5, 45), (9, 9, 81), (7, 5, 35), (7, 9, 63), (5, 9, 45)]
```

También se puede hacer con comprensión de listas:

```
Num = [1, 9, 7, 5, 9]
# Comprensión de listas que genera tuplas de 3 elementos
# (multiplicando, multiplicador, producto)
resultados = [(Num[n], m, Num[n] * m) for n in range(len(Num)) for m in Num[n+1:]]
print(resultados)
```

Que imprime lo siguiente:

```
[(1, 9, 9), (1, 7, 7), (1, 5, 5), (1, 9, 9), (9, 7, 63), (9, 5, 45), (9, 9, 81), (7, 5, 35), (7, 9, 63), (5, 9, 45)]
```

**Nota:** Las tuplas las cree únicamente para ejemplificar como funciona el código y que veas que los valores son multiplicados correctamente. En tu caso no necesitas la tupla sino únicamente el producto por lo que podrías modificar esa parte para obtener únicamente el valor de los productos.

Answer (score 4):

Probablemente hay formas mas cortas pero esta es una forma

```
def  Buscar(dato,Num):
   for x in range(0,len(Num)):#el primer for es para el valor que multiplica 
      for i in range(0,len(Num)): #el segundo para recorrer la variable
       if x!=i and dato==Num[x]*Num[i]: #sale si el resultado se coincide con el resultado de la multiplicación y los índices no coincide 
         return True
       
   return False #sale, ya que el resultado no coincide con ninguno

Num = [1,9,7,5,9]
dato= float( input("Introducir resultado posible:"))

if Buscar(dato,Num):
   print("Coincide")
else:
   print("No coincide")
```

Answer (score 4):

Si la cuestión es ver si un valor proviene de multiplicar dos elementos **distintos** de la lista, una solución más corta es:

```
def encontrar(lista, valor):
    for num in lista:
        if num:
            cuociente = valor / num
            if cuociente != num and cuociente in lista:
                return True
    return False
```

La función toma el valor y lo usa para dividir cada elemento en la lista. Si la división arroja un resultado que ya está en la lista, significa que se encontraron los dos factores que dan el valor.

**Demo**

```
lista = [0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9]
for i in range(40):
    print(i, encontrar(lista, i))
```

produce:

```
0 True
1 False
2 False
3 False
4 False
5 False
6 True
7 False
8 False
9 False
10 True
11 False
12 False
13 False
14 False
15 True
16 True
17 False
18 True
19 False
20 False
21 False
22 False
23 False
24 True
25 False
26 False
27 True
28 False
29 False
30 False
31 False
32 False
33 False
34 False
35 False
36 False
37 False
38 False
39 False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ¿por qué el `num != valor`? Creo que solo tiene sentido si la lista no puede contener unos.

Comment: @abulafia. Quedo de una primera versión que hacía supuestos sobre la lista que finalmente no resultaron ciertos. Lo elimine; nada cambio.